# How to avoid copying the entire dojo library every time creating a new Java EE package to be deployed on glassfish?

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, dojo, glassfish, cometd

I am learning comet programming, using cometd implementation and javascript dojo library then deploying my war files to GlassFish. Every time I create a new project I have to include the entire dojo library to every single war file, I tried to copy only the needed elements of the dojo library preserving the same path structure but it didn't work.

So can i avoid including the entire dojo library every time creating a new Java EE package to be deployed on GlassFish?

Answer (score 1):

In GlassFish, there's this concept of an "alternate doc root" which allows you to map resources external to you application in to its context. In your WARs you can add entries to your {sun|glassfish}-web.xml file to capture these bindings. This way you have the code in central place on your server, outside of Glassfish, and map it in to each of your WARs.

Note that this is specific to GlassFish, and not portable to other Java EE containers (though others may well have a similar mechanism).